# Is it still possible to use the old-style plugin for libreoffice without the UNO-Overhead?

Tags: add-in, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm using LibreOffice 5.0.6.3 on a Linux machine (openSuSE 13.2). [Here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Add-in_for_Programming_in_Calc) I found an article how to easily write an add-in without the overhead of the UNO API. In the beginning there is a warning, that this method is outdated, but still supported. But when I try to import my shared library in libreoffice the following error appears:

```
no symbol "component_writeInfo" in component library <file:///home/username/.config/libreoffice/4-suse/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages/lu27745lr6l0g.tmp_/oolinint2d.so>
```

Reading this error message, I suppose, that libreoffice is looking for some UNO component.

I see two possibilities:

- I made some error in the library, so that LibreOffice doesn't recognize the old format
- LibreOffice doesn't support the old format of add-ins any more

How do I find out, which one is true?

Answer (score 1):

From looking at `InitExternalFunc` in the [source code](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/tree/sc/source/core/tool/callform.cxx), it may still be possible, although to my knowledge, no one does it this way anymore.

You tried to import the library -- what does that mean precisely?  According to the page:

> LibreOffice searches the Add-in folder defined in the configuration for a suitable DLLshared library.

Be sure that you are using the correct location (and I cannot tell you where that is; sorry).

From the question, it looks like you tried to include it as part of an UNO package instead, which doesn't seem right, because then it would expect a component, right?  The error message seems to indicate that is what went wrong.

I have always created add-ins [this way](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Spreadsheet_Add-Ins) instead.